# Trying to fetch data using POST but data returns as null? I am confused

Tags: javascript, mysql, macos

I am trying to get data from my front-end and store it in backend, however everytime I try to return it I receive `{ name: '' } in the terminal instead of the name I have inserted.

I have also tried to use Inspect Element to tell me where the error arises but it's not helping me as much.

Have attached my code below.

The code seems to cancel out the second "name" when I try to fetch data from localhost.

Any ideas. I have also attached screenshot for further clarity.

Thanks!

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
fetch('http://localhost:5001/getAll')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => loadHTMLTable(data['name']));


});

const addButton = document.querySelector('#add-name-button');

addButton.onclick = function () {
    const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name-input');
    constname = nameInput.value;
    nameInput.value = '';

    fetch('http://localhost:5001/insert',{
        headers:{
            'Content-type': 'application/json' 
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ name : name })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => insertRowIntoTable(data['data']));
    

}

function insertRowIntoTable(data){
    
}

function loadHTMLTable(data) {
    const table = document.querySelector('table tbody');

    console.log(data);
    

    if (data.length === 0){
        table.innerHTML = "<tr><td class = 'no-data' colspan = '5'> No Data </td></tr>";

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be POST-ing `nameInput.value` instead of `name`, which you're not defining anywhere in the provided code.

Comment: can you please further elaborate? I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

`constname = nameInput.value;` should be `const name = nameInput.value;`
You should be using 'use strict' to avoid such errors(?) or a more advanced tools like linting etc.

Comment: This should just be flagged as a typo.

Comment: So a comment would have been more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that's how we normally deal with typos.

Comment: OH MY GOD! Thank you so much!!! One more q. If I only want it to return the input I put in instead of "{name: "ashdiueh"}, how would I go about that?

Comment: @user14650291, you would use `console.log(data.name)` or `console.log(data['name'])`